# How to select the first selement from the sequence returned by Xpath

Tags: xpath, firebug, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a specific web-element: input field which belongs to the class "selectDateTime" and is located next to the label "From". Actually XPath query

```
//fieldset[legend="Pickup"]//div[@class="selectDateTime"]
```

founds this element, but another one element of the same class presents on the page. I tried to select the first or the last element using following XPath query

//fieldset[legend="Pickup"]//div[@class="selectDateTime"][1]
  (//fieldset[legend="Pickup"]//div[@class="selectDateTime"])[1]

But in the 1st case the query founds 2 elements, in the second case query doesn't produce a result. Do you know, how can I resolve this problem? May be, you have a work-around? You're welcome with your ideas.

Here is the XML which is parsed:

```
[fieldset]
    [legend]
        Pickup
    [/legend]
    [div class="block block_position_first"]
        [div class="tr"]
            [div class="td"]
                [label]
                    From:
                [/label]
            [/div]
            [div class="td"]
                [div class="selectDateTime"]
                    [input class="date" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/]
                    [input class="time" type="text" placeholder="00:00"/]
                [/div]
            [/div]
        [/div]
        [div class="tr"]
            [div class="td"]
                [label]
                    To:
                [/label]
            [/div]
            [div class="td"]
                [div class="selectDateTime"]
                    [input class="date" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/]
                    [input class="time" type="text" placeholder="00:00"/]
                [/div]
            [/div]
        [/div]
    [/div]
[/fieldset]
```

There are some problems with posting the XML-file, so I've replace < and > with [ and ] respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[1]` for the first element and `[last()]` for the last one. Make sure to add appropriate parentheses, otherwise you will receive the first or last element of each run for the last step expression.

```
(//fieldset[legend="Pickup"]//div[@class="selectDateTime"])[1]
(//fieldset[legend="Pickup"]//div[@class="selectDateTime"])[last()]
```

Comment: Sorry, but my Firebug tells me, that there are no elements which matches this query

Comment: Please post (some of) your data.